# pythonic way to join a list with or without the last element based on condition

Tags: python

The idea is to decide whether to include the last element for a list based on a flag, and then join the list.

My current way seems a bit redundant, and I am wondering if there is other better way to express it in one line without more redundancy.

```
'/'.join([a, b, c, d] if flag else [a, b, c])
```

Comment: You could always do `'/'.join([a, b, c] + ([d] if flag else []))`, or even `'/'.join([a, b, c, d][:4 if flag else 3])`. But I don't think these are much better, even if they avoid the repetition. Why does it have to be on one line in the first place?

Comment: `'/'.join(mylist if flag else mylist[:-1])`

Comment: @abarnert the reason it should be in one line is that, this statement is actually in another list comprehension. I try not to revamp the entire list comprehension :/

Comment: Any comprehension that includes sub-expressions too complex for you to deal with almost certainly _does_ need to be revamped. Or, alternatively, leave it as a list comprehension, but pull the bits out into separate functions that you can name, test, debug, etc., even if the comprehension is the only place you use them.

Comment: You could do `'/'.join('ABCD'[:flag-1 or None])` or `'/'.join('ABCD'[:(-1, None)[flag]])` or `'/'.join('ABCD'[:{0:-1}.get(flag)])`.